# Laravel Create Date return different format

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I tried to select the create_data from the database, the date format in the database is like "2021-05-18 11:06:01", but when I retrieve and display it, it's will show the format like is "2021-05-18T03:06:01.000000Z". Does anyone know why will become like that? I want the date which is actually like the database store which is "2021-05-18 11:06:01". However, the create_date inside DB the format is UTC +8, but when receive it will show UTC format.

[image]

**Data return**

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [log_name] => login
    [description] => login
    [subject_type] => App\Models\Users
    [subject_id] => 0
    [causer_type] => App\Models\User
    [causer_id] => 2
    [properties] => ""         
    [created_at] => 2021-05-18T03:06:01.000000Z
);
```

**Code**

```
$lastLoggedActivity = ActivityLog::where('causer_id', $userid)
    ->orWhereIn('subject_id', $selectparentid)
    ->with('getLogType')
    ->with('getCauserDetails')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: `created_at` is by default a carbon instance, so the format is like that. you can format it any way you want.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon, even i set the app.php (timezone) to what I want, the date also will return format like this is it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `serializeDate` method to your model to change it's format on responses.

```php
/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: this function helps to change the dates column format using one function

Answer (score 6):

In ActivityLog model add this,

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because laravel auto cast created_at and updated_at, you can readmore at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) and to change created_at add to model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
];
```

Comment: Hi, seems like inside the DB the format is UTC +8, but when receive it will show UTC format.

Comment: you can change how laravel store timezone by changing timezone in config/app.php

Comment: set ald, but still same

Comment: become 2021-05-18 03:06:01, instead of 2021-05-18 11:06:01

Comment: it only affect with new record insert

Answer (score 1):

I had to use mutators just like [@yudiz-solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580177/2365006) above but could not achieve exactly what I wanted until I added timezone value:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->timezone('Africa/Nairobi')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

OR

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->timezone('Africa/Nairobi')->toDateTimeString();
}
```

NB: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting-and-timezones) recommends use of UTC timezone:

> Consistently using the UTC timezone throughout your application will
> provide the maximum level of interoperability with other date
> manipulation libraries written in PHP and JavaScript.